# What to use to save website offline including externally-referenced media?

Tags: web-development, chrome, offline, firefox, safari

I am trying to save a site that includes externally-referenced media in javascript media players, flash players, HTML5 media players.

Using Chrome Save As, the external references are being preserved, but what I really want to happen is for the external media to be captured and then external links replaced by local links.

I am on MAC.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Several years ago I used the command-line-tool `wget`. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the most known website copier is [**HTTrack**](http://www.httrack.com/) but it is not available on Mac...

For Mac I'd suggest [**SiteSucker**](http://ricks-apps.com/osx/sitesucker/index.html), though I'm not sure how powerful it is.

Comment: Will get on a windows machine and try out HTTRack - thanks!